# Recursive function that takes a string as argument and determines if the string has more vowels than consonants

Tags: python, recursion

Why doesn't this work?:

```
def recursiveVowels(str):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    vowels_count =0
    if len(str) == 0:
        return vowels_count
    elif str[0] in vowels:
        vowels_count += 1

    total_vowels =   vowels_count + recursiveVowels(str[1:])
    # check if no of vowels are more than half the length of string
    return total_vowels > (len(str)/2)
```

this will return `False`.

```
print(recursiveVowels("Targeiout"))
```

but if I do this it works fine:

```
def recursiveVowels(str):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    vowels_count =0
    if len(str) == 0:
        return vowels_count
    elif str[0] in vowels:
        vowels_count += 1

    total_vowels =   vowels_count + recursiveVowels(str[1:])
    return total_vowels

# made a seperate function just to check if vowels are more than consonants
def isVowelsMore(str):
    vowels = recursiveVowels(str)
    return (len(str)/2) < vowels
```

this will return `True`:

```
print(isVowelsMore("Targeiout"))
```

Need some conceptual clarity.

Comment: in the recursion the output is used to construct the next one, so if you return a boolean... in `total_vowels = ...` you are concatenating boolean with `int`. But `bool` are automatically cast  to integer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with others that the second version of your function is the way to go, but I would write it like:

```
def isVowelsMore(string):
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}

    def recursiveVowels(string, index=0):
        vowels_count = 0

        if index >= len(string):
            return vowels_count

        if string[index] in vowels:
            vowels_count += 1

        return vowels_count + recursiveVowels(string, index + 1)

    vowels = recursiveVowels(string)

    return len(string) / 2 < vowels
```

The `index` variable was added to avoid creating a new string on every recursive call -- you can continue doing that and still use the above framework.  I also switched your `list` of vowels to a `set` for improved performance.  And I renamed your `str` variable as that's a Python builtin name which shouldn't be redefined.

Answer (score 1):

your first recursion returns boolean
so when you are calling this line

```
total_vowels =   vowels_count + recursiveVowels(str[1:])
```

what actually happens is

```
 total_vowels =   vowels_count + False
```

or

```
total_vowels =   vowels_count + True
```

and that means that total_vowels value is at most vowels_count+1 (in case recursiveVowels(str[1:]) returned True), which means its at most 2 so your function will return false for any string longer than 4

hope I could help,
feel free to ask for any clarification in the comments :)

Comment: total_vowel count will come out to be 5 in this case if I just return the total_vowel. So far what I understood about recursion is that function call will suspend until the next call is returned so I do not think this is doing vowels_count + False. The issue is I think somewhere after that may be in this line return (len(str)/2) < vowels but I am sure yet what that is.

Comment: if you return `total_vowel` you completely change the recurtion, the returned value will be 5 since you changed all the recursion calls, not only the first one. try printing the value of `total_vowel`  right before you return it to see that it wont rise above 2 (in this case it wont even rise above 1)

Comment: if you still don't understand anything feel free to comment, and if my answer helped you please consider marking it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're returning a boolean. When used with greater than or less than, False is interpreted to 0, True is interpreted to 1. (See the documentation on [Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=boolean#numeric-types-int-float-complex) for more about how Booleans are a subtype of integers).

So your first recursive function is adding 1 or 0 based on ... `total_vowels > (len(str)/2)`, which is clearly not what you intend.

I'd suggest using the second version with the wrapper function.

Comment: strange it is returning True to me

Comment: "When used with greater than or less than, False is cast to 0, True is cast to 1." strictly speaking, there is no casting going on.

Comment: Check my updated answer. The difference has to do a) what happens when you try to add 'False' or 'True' to an int, and b) when you evaluate vowels vs non-vowels, which probably should be outside the recursion.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I learned something today.

Comment: that is the precise reason I made a separate return instead of doing this  .. return True if vowels_count + recursiveVowels(str[1:]) > (len(str)/2) else False  . What I was assuming was that recursion would be over by the time code will reach the last line and therefore comparison can be done. But I am not sure if that's what's happening.